# Unable to re-produce valid data for d attribute of a path

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, path

When I create the first set of sectors in my pie chart, it works great. Especially, the attribute d of each path is set correctly.

```
var grx = chart.selectAll(".sector").data(pie(dataPoints))
  .enter().append("g").attr("class", "sector");
grx.append("path").attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return colorsFull(d.value); });
```

Then, I try to use the same pattern to add a new, inner pie chart. The elements are created, which I can confirm by investigating the DOM structure. However, they're not displayed and, even though it's not shown in the console of the JsFiddle, I got it to have a bunch of NaN.

```
var gry = chart.selectAll(".subSector").data(pie(drillData))
  .enter().append("g").attr("class", "subSector");
gry.append("path").attr("d", sub)
  .style("fill", function(d) {return colorsDrill(d.value); });
```

So, I've got an invalid data for the path but I can't see how it goes wrong. Suggestions?

The fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/9u8wc65u/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `drillData` is not in the correct format to pass to your `pie` function.  It looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Category 1",
    "val": [{ "Category": "", "Key": "", Value: 1}, ... ]
  }
  ...
]
```

Your pie function, though, is expecting an array of objects with a property `val` that's a **number**, not an array (this is what the `.value` does).

I'm guessing you need to subset your `drillData` to the one you clicked on something like:

```
 var subData = null;
 drillData.forEach(function(d,i){
   if (d.key === key) subData = drillData[i].val;
 });
```

You now have in `subData` an array of objects with a property **Value** that's a number.  We are getting closer but now we need to redefine our pie function since it's expecting **val**, not Value:

```
pie.value(function(d){
  return d.Value;
});
```

So, now we can finally call:

```
pie(subData)
```

without error.  **But**, we still got a problem, now you are trying to build an inner donut chart with 300+ wedges (it ain't going to be pretty).

Here's an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9u8wc65u/4/) where I started fixing things.

Comment: Great insight! The thing you did got me going. Of course, in the actual solution I want the data to be presented grouped by the subcategory [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/9u8wc65u/) but that's my job to do. Upvote indeed.